# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - Highcharts - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm trying to use Highcharts in my MVC web application. I have loaded all the prerequisites to make Highcharts working. But apparently, "highchart" is still not recognized by the page. I'm checking the rendered page by google developer tool and it says all the JQuery and Highchart javascript files are loaded properly. Any help?

This is my .cshtml code:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>



@section Scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/modules/exporting.js")


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var chart;
        debugger;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            debugger;

            // Build the chart
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Browser share',
                    data: [
                        ['Firefox', 45.0],
                        ['IE', 26.8],
                        {
                            name: 'Chrome',
                            y: 12.8,
                            sliced: true,
                            selected: true
                        },
                        ['Safari', 8.5],
                        ['Opera', 6.2],
                        ['Others', 0.7]
                    ]
                }]
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
}
```

Comment: i used them it worked for me,see my tutorial may be it helps:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/09/bar-charts-and-graphs-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Thanks man! It worked. But it's weird!In the original samples from Highcarts website, it goes like "$("#container").highcharts(....)" which I was using and It's working on a simple html page but not in my MVC application. This one in your page is working just fine!

Comment: Yes it happens I also faced issues but this way id worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this does the trick (which is kind of weird!) :

I need to change this line:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
```

To this line:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },
```

This is the link which helped me through: http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/09/bar-charts-and-graphs-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: @SebastianBochan This does work but I still cannot mark my own answer as correct. It needs 2days to be passed.